# problema con http get angular 5

Tags: angular5

el problema es que el método me está retornando `undefinded` el código es

```
    getLugares() {
    this._http.get(this.url + 'lugar')  //usar la url que corresponda
      .map(res => res)
      .subscribe(
        res => this.lugares=res,
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('Funciona!')
      );
  }
```

No es problema del web service ni de la URL porque ya los probé. Además al cambiar la linea 5 así `res => console.log(res),` en el log me aparece el array  de forma correcta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema parece ser `this.lugares`, en ese scope `this` ya no se refiere a tu objeto original, por lo que utilizar una variable `that` puede ayudarte:

```
 getLugares() {
    const that = this
    that._http.get(that.url + 'lugar')  //usar la url que corresponda
      .map(res => res)
      .subscribe(
        res => that.lugares=res,
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('Funciona!')
      );
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta es la solución